# Как добавить css class к родителям <td> при условии если содержимое td повторяется в таблице

Tags: php, jquery

Подскажите как я могу подсветить (используя jQuery) именно те блоки 'tr', в которых есть совпадающие содержимое в 'td'. В данном случае, например, одинаковый 'Номер заказа'? 
Таблица берется из SQL, перебирается в цикле и подставляется в разметку, нужно динамически подкрашивать строки таблицы с одним номером заказа. Заранее спасибо за помощь!

```
<table border="1" width="80%"  cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
<tr>
    <th>Дата Внесения</th>
    <th>Номер заказа</th>
    <th>Ф.И.О.</th>
    <th>Исследование</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>11.10.18</td>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>Булкина Э.П.</td>
    <td>Биохимия</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>11.10.18</td>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>Булкина Э.П.</td>
    <td>Общ.клинич. анализ</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>11.10.18</td>
    <td>456</td>
    <td>Втулкина Я.О.</td>
    <td>Исследование ПЦР</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: делайте это на стороне сервера в пхп. Заведите себе два класса для строк. Строки выводите циклом, номер заказа в отдельную переменную, как в строке сменился номер, меняете класс. Опять сменился - меняете обратно. Отсортировать надо, конечно по номеру заказа только.

Comment: Вам нужен пример выделения строк с одинаковыми номерами заказа на jquery ?

Comment: Да, было бы неплохо.=) Способ который предложил  teran, пока не смог протестировать.

Comment: Teran, не соображу как мне отслеживать сменился ли номер заказа? Не мог бы ты пример кода привести? Я начинающий, могу подтупливать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте это на jquery, хотя я написал, но не проверял:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('tr').each(function(){
    var num=$(this).children('td').eq(1).text();
    $('tr').not(this).each(function(){
      if(num==$(this).children('td').eq(1).text()) {
        $(this).children('td').eq(1).css('background-color','red');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Не работает код, к сожалению.

Comment: А ошибку выдает? Вы его в теги script завернули?

Comment: Исправил маленько, там скобки были пропущены

Comment: Спасибо большое, работает! Правда страница подгружаться медленнее стала с моей таблицей, буду пробовать на стороне php.

Comment: Отметьте галочкой ответ,если не затруднит